# Failed to connect to: localhost:27017: Connection refused

Tags: php, mongodb, xampp, ubuntu-14.04

I have installed MongoDB in xampp on Ubuntu using Laravel 5.1. But I always get this error

> MongoConnectionException in TestController.php line 19: Failed to
>   connect to: localhost:27017: Connection refused

Nor I'm able 
I have gone through a lot of questions, but all proved to be trivial solution.

Please help me with this as I'm stuck on it.

Comment: "Connection refused" is mostly associated with firewalls or misconfiguration.  Your error logs for MongoDB will say more.

Comment: It's a configuration problem, you can try `127.0.0.1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that first thing to do is to ssh on that server and check that mongod process is alive, then try open mongo shell using command - mongo . If all works try telnet on this server and port from your machine ,if there is no errors , read mongo logs

Comment: Thanks! That was really helpful. Actually mongod server was not running. Being a newbie I didn't noticed it.